# How to programatically move the desired row to the top of datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, datatable

I have a datatable with data loaded by AJAX. I want to modify it, so when the users visit mypage/ the datatable would highlight the according row and move it to the top of the table. I've already achieved highlighting the row with this code:

```
        "rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
        if ( data.id == given_id ) {
            $(row).addClass('success');
            console.log(index);
        }
    }
```

and it works, but the problem appears when this row is on, say, 10th page. The datatables displays only first page when user enters the webpage. I want to programatically change the pagination to desired page or move the row to the top of the table, so when the user enters he would see 'his' row on the top. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed my problem. The solution was as follows:

1. I've added additional `<th>` in the html table structure.
2. Then I've added the following code in the datatable rendering code:

   ```
   var table = $("#table_placeholder").dataTable( {
   "ajax": Routing.generate('myAjaxUrl'),
   "columns": [
       {
           "visible": false,
           "data":"user_id",
           "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
               return data == displayUserId ? 1 : 0;
           }
       },
       //-rest of the code-
   ```

   where the ***user_id*** is the id imported from the database and ***displayUserId*** is the ID that has been passed via url argument and stored in a hidden html input.
3. I've added the following lines at the end of the datatable rendering code:

   ```
   "rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
       if ( data.user_id == displayUserId ) {
           $(row).addClass('highlighted-row');
           console.log(index);
       }
   },
   "order":[[0,'desc']]
   ```

   The ***rowCallback*** function allows me to highlight the row and then I user ***order*** on the hidden column from 2. This brings the desired row to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth adding a timestamp column, and ordering by it on select,

Or you could get the `sortid` of the top row, increment all `sortid`'s in your database, then inserting your new row and setting its `sortid` to the one that old top row had previously.